# Plotting PCA with ggbiplot results in labels overlapping. How to plot with PCA with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggrepel

I am trying to plot principle components. I am using the following code. One problem I am running into is that the labels for variables are too close to each other. I read that using ggrepel solves this problem.

Here is an example data

EDIT1: Making changes to create a reproducible output

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(
  Diet = sample(1:2),
  Outcome1 = sample(1:10),
  Outcome2 = sample(11:20),
  Outcome3 = sample(21:30),
  Response1 = sample(31:40),
  Response2 = sample(41:50),
  Response3 = sample(51:60)
)

ir.pca <- prcomp(dat[,3:5], center = TRUE, scale. = TRUE) 

summary(ir.pca)

loadings <- ir.pca$rotation

scores <- ir.pca$x

correlations <- t(loadings)*ir.pca$sdev

plot(ir.pca, type = "l",main="")

ggbiplot(ir.pca, choices=c(1,2), obs.scale = 1, var.scale = 1)

dat2 <- as.data.frame(dat)
ggbiplot(ir.pca, choices=c(1,2), # creates a plot with ellipse
         groups=dat2[,1],
         obs.scale = 1, 
         var.scale = 1, 
         ellipse = TRUE)
```

What do I have to do, to plot the same graph in ggplot? So that I can use ggrepel?

Comment: Can you post a picture of what you have so far? The final line of code doesn't look any different for me than the second-to-last line.

Comment: @cardinal40 please see the reproducible code now. I have made changes to it so that it should work for you. It had some errors. This is just an example code, where the labels do not overlap. In my actual code the labels overlap. I would like to know how to run this code in ggplot to use ggrepel?

Comment: Probably if you replaced `geom_text` with `ggrepel::geom_text_repel()` in [all the right places](https://github.com/vqv/ggbiplot/blob/master/R/ggbiplot.r#L171)...

Comment: Yeah, the package creator has done a lot behind the scenes to create the plots in your revised code. You are likely to be best off copy and pasting from Roman's link above and replacing the `geom_text` calls as needed to create a modified `ggbiplot()` function.

Comment: @cardinal40 the best solution would be to form the repository, create a testing branch and try it out. This is not very hard to do.

Comment: Thanks everyone. This worked! Appreciate your help.

Comment: Just a suggestion: check the function fviz_pca in the factoextra package